# Допустимо ли в конкретном контексте "хоть... но ведь"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Однако папа Климент XII хоть и указал на фасаде: “Климент XII понтифик
>   украсил акведук девы и освятил его великолепие богослужением в 1735
>   году, в шестой год своего понтификата”, но ведь так и не дождался
>   окончания работ.

[image: Фасад фонтана Треви]

Comment: Вряд ли возможно привести связный пример с таким сочетанием оговорок. По минимуму здесь нужно заменить "но ведь" на "он". Либо можно вместо странного "хотя... но ведь" употребить "хотя... (он) тем не менее" или "хотя... (он) однако". Это какой-то перевод?

Comment: Нет, это авторская стилистика, авторские акценты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагается замена:  ...но  **при этом** так и не дождался окончания работ.

Непонятно, что в приведенном предложении выражает частица ***ведь***.

Сравнить:  Почему он сделал такую надпись, ведь он так  и не дождался окончания работ.